# ActiveRecord query based on multiple objects via has_many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Product` class that `has_many` `Gender` through `Connection` class instances.  I want to query to find products that have both `end_a` and `end_b` present.  The current class method works with 2 caveats:

- Fails to return correctly if searching where `end_a` and `end_b` are the same.  Instead should search if `product` has 2 instances, not just one of object.
- Returns an `Array` when I want an `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

The class method `.query` is below, any feedback or ideas are appreciated.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many   :connections, dependent: :destroy, as: :connectionable
  has_many   :genders,     through:   :connections

  def self.query(end_a, end_b)
    search_base = active.joins(:connections)
    end_a_search = search_base.where(connections: { gender_id: end_a  } )

    end_a_search & search_base.where(connections: { gender_id: end_b  } )
  end
end
```

ps: Once this is figured out will likely move this to a scope for `Product`

Comment: What are connection? Join model?

Comment: @BroiSatse Fixed the above, but `Genders` belongs to `Product` through `Connections`

Comment: `scope :some_query , ->(end_a, end_b) Product.joins(:connections).where("connections.gender_id = ? OR connections.gender_id = ?", end_a, end_b)`

Comment: @bjhaid I don't think that would work since it would return instances of product that only have a relationship with `end_a` or `end_b` as well. I need the product to have a relationship with both `end_a` and `end_b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy, as: :connectionable
  has_many :genders, through: :connections

  scope :with_genders, -> (end_a, end_b) {
    relation = joins('INNER JOIN connections c1 ON c1.connectionable_id = products.id AND c1.connectionable_type = \'Product\'')
      .joins('INNER JOIN connections c2 ON c1.connectionable_id = c2.connectionable_id AND c2.connectionable_type = \'Product\'')
      .where(c1: {gender_id: end_a}, c2: {gender_id: end_b})
      .group('products.id')
    end_a == end_b ? relation.having('COUNT(products.id) > 1') : relation
  }
end
```

Comment: I apologize but the `connections` is polymorphic so when I tried the above and even replaced `product_id` with `connectionable_id` it still failed to return correctly if searching where `end_a` and `end_b` are the same.

Comment: See the updated response. Also in future try to provide all necessary information in your question - by doing it you save time of those people who help you.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning the polymorphic model before.  But I implemented your updated scope and am getting an error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "Product" does not exist LINE 1`. Thank you for all your help thus far.

Comment: Thanks for the updating and now the code is running but not covering the caveat I mentioned in the initial post: "Fails to return correctly if searching where `end_a` and `end_b` are the same. Instead should search if product has 2 instances, not just one of object."  Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, probably I didn't read the description carefully enough. See the final update, is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Trushkevich.  Your work allows the query for [this](http://cablefinder.herokuapp.com). Try XLR Male and XLR Female.

Comment: ha, nice, now I see why you need that )